# robocopy treats options as files

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, git-bash, robocopy

When i use robocopy to copy a file and use the option `/IS` to overwrite if already present at the destination. It treats the option as another file as can be seen by the logs: `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "C:/Program Files/Git/IS"`

Anybody knows how to copy files in windows while overwriting the file at the destination.

```
$ robocopy "Z:\ubuntushare" "C:\Natlink\Natlink\MacroSystem" "_git.py" /IS

   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

  Started : Sat Sep 17 18:00:05 2016

   Source - Z:\ubuntushare\
     Dest - C:\Natlink\Natlink\MacroSystem\

    Files : _git.py

  Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "C:/Program Files/Git/IS"

       Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?


****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !

pri@pri-PC MINGW64 /c/NatLink/NatLink/MacroSystem
```

Answer (score 9):

**edited** 2016/09/19 - Tested and it works

From the [MinGW Posix path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion)

> An argument starting with 2 or more / is considered an escaped Windows
>   style switch and will be passed with the leading / removed and all \
>   changed to /.
>
> - Except that if there is a / following the leading block of /, the argument is considered to be a UNC path and the leading / is not
>     removed.

*note*: this is just a *small* extract of the full list. it is better to read the full list when working with the git bash shell in windows

So, in this case, the solution is to double the forward slash in the switch

```dos
robocopy "Z:\ubuntushare" "C:\Natlink\Natlink\MacroSystem" "_git.py" //IS
```

Comment: Wow.  Some of those rules are *bizarre.*

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I have to agree, but also I'm glad someone has thought about the coexistence of the two systems

Answer (score 4):

ROBOCOPY uses the windows style forward slash `/` to specify command line options. That doesn't work well with Git-bash or similar terminals since the slash is interpreted as the `root` path in Linux and similar environments.

The shell is interpreting the `/something` as a file `something` under the root folder `C:\Program Files\Git\` and not a command line option. So that ends up meaning `"C:\Program Files\Git\something"` which doesn't exist.

Even trying to use the help option `/?` fails with a similar error.

<del>Use the linux/unix/mac standard `-opt` instead of `/opt`.</del> Robocopy allows using dash/hyphen `-` to specify options. eg `robocopy -?` works and shows usage info/help. So do:

```
robocopy "Z:\ubuntushare" "C:\Natlink\Natlink\MacroSystem" "_git.py" -IS
```

Comment: That depends on the fact that robocopy accepts `-` instead of `/` though.  Surely there's a more generic way to tell the shell not to mess with the command line?

Comment: @HarryJohnston +1 did not know that Robocopy explicitly allows it and hence works. Will edit my answer. So I presume all windows commands using `/opts` would result in this error? Found it surprising that escaping the `/` with `\/` didn't work either.